# Simple Default Wix MSIX Project Throws a FgExcludeDarwinFeatures Error On Build

Tags: wix, msix

I'm testing out the MSIX features of the WiX framework. When I attempt to build I receive the following error:

> light.exe(0,0): error LGHT0221: The definition for the
> 'FgExcludeDarwinFeatures' table's 'Feature_' column is a foreign key
> relationship to the 'Feature' table's column number 1.  The
> modularization types of the two column definitions differ: one is
> Column and the other is None.  Change one of the modularization types
> so that they match.

My setup:

Followed installation instructions from: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/getting-started

Created a default wix setup project in visual studio 2019. Included FgMsixExtension.wixext.dll, included the fgmsix.xsd property on Wix element.

I'm running toolset v3.11.2.4516 (latest). Expansion Pack v3.11.476 - 2020-12-22 (latest)

**Project compiles fine without the MSIX line, and the inclusion of the FgMsixExtension.wixext**

Any ideas what I am missing?

Also does anyone have a working WiX msix example I can also compare to?

Just in case it is needed, here is a very quick edit of the default setup project from a wix template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:fga="http://www.firegiant.com/schemas/v3/wxs/fgmsix.xsd">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject3" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="test1" UpgradeCode="77c4b832-ed73-4ba2-825c-7eee7837a8f4">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <fga:Msix Id="testy" Publisher="CN=test1" Target="desktop" />
    <!--<fga:Application Id="MyApp" ExecutableFile="prodFile" />-->
    
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="test.cab" EmbedCab="yes" /> 
    
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject3" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject3" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Id="prodFile" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\FireGiant.LicensingTool.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished a conversation with FireGiant Support. This was due to a bug:

> The dev team published the fix in v3.11.479. This should solve the issue you faced.
>
> Let us know if you have any other questions or problems.
>
> Happy packaging!
>
> -- FireGiant Support

v3.11.479 released 01/15/2021